# How can I get CSharp / .NET to "play nice" with PHP-encrypted strings?

Tags: c#, php, .net, http, encryption

(preface: I'm a newbie with encryption and security, figured this would be a fun way to learn)

I'm building a program in C# that communicates with a server written in PHP using standard HTTP protocol.  I want both programs to be able to send and receive encrypted data.  However, there appear to be inconsistencies regarding how the encryption is being handled, despite them both using the same kind of functions.

Both programs use Rjindael 128 bit in CBC mode.

For demonstration / testing, I made two functions that are virtually identical, each taking the same string, encrypting it, and spitting out the result as a base64 string.

The PHP function:

```
public static function EncryptionTest () {
  echo 'Testing Encryption to base64 string...<br/>';

  $originalString = 'This is the original String! How cool is that?';

  $key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345";
  $iv = "1234567890123456";

  $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $originalString, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

  echo base64_encode ($encrypted);
}
```

And it's C# counterpart:

```
public static void EncryptionTest ()
{
  System.Console.WriteLine ("Testing Encryption to base64 string...");

  string originalString = "This is the original String! How cool is that?";
  byte [] encryptedData;
  byte [] key = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345");
  byte [] iv = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("1234567890123456");

  RijndaelManaged cryptor = new RijndaelManaged ();
  cryptor.Key = key;
  cryptor.IV = iv;
  cryptor.BlockSize = 128;
  cryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

  ICryptoTransform encryptor = cryptor.CreateEncryptor (cryptor.Key, cryptor.IV);

  using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream ())
  {
    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream (msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
      using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter (csEncrypt) )
      {
        swEncrypt.Write (originalString);
      }
      encryptedData = msEncrypt.ToArray ();
    }
  }

  System.Console.WriteLine (System.Convert.ToBase64String (encryptedData) );
}
```

Now, here is the PHP result:

> Testing Encryption to base64 string...
>   yzwIdowhLj+cMOFPMuHSA80pWQ6R8yfFQlEsLx5kIzUOJdFykLjsaKfK4VfaBGRv

And the C# result:

> Testing Encryption to base64 string...
>   yzwIdowhLj+cMOFPMuHSA80pWQ6R8yfFQlEsLx5kIzUg74mGEQf9iW+OQ68m6cpp

As you can see, the two results are clearly encrypted (good), are the same number of characters (good), but are different (could be bad).

I wrote decryption tests which take these strings and process them.  Here is the PHP function:

```
public static function DecryptionTest () {
  $phpBase64 = 'yzwIdowhLj+cMOFPMuHSA80pWQ6R8yfFQlEsLx5kIzUOJdFykLjsaKfK4VfaBGRv';
  $csBase64 =  'yzwIdowhLj+cMOFPMuHSA80pWQ6R8yfFQlEsLx5kIzUg74mGEQf9iW+OQ68m6cpp';

  $key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345";
  $iv = "1234567890123456";

  $phpEncrypted = base64_decode ($phpBase64);
  $phpDecrypted = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $phpEncrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

  $csEncrypted = base64_decode ($csBase64);
  $csDecrypted = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $csEncrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

  echo 'Decrypted PHP string: "' . $phpDecrypted . '"<br/>' .
       'Decrypted CS string:  "' . $csDecrypted . '"';
}
```

And the C# version:

```
public static void DecryptionTest ()
{
  System.Console.WriteLine ("Testing Decryption for PHP and CS generated base64 strings!");

  string phpBase64 = "yzwIdowhLj+cMOFPMuHSA80pWQ6R8yfFQlEsLx5kIzUOJdFykLjsaKfK4VfaBGRv";
  string csBase64 = "yzwIdowhLj+cMOFPMuHSA80pWQ6R8yfFQlEsLx5kIzUg74mGEQf9iW+OQ68m6cpp";

  byte [] phpEncrypted = System.Convert.FromBase64String (phpBase64);
  byte [] csEncrypted = System.Convert.FromBase64String (csBase64);

  string phpDecrypted;
  string csDecrypted;

  byte [] encryptedData;
  byte [] key = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345");
  byte [] iv = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("1234567890123456");

  RijndaelManaged cryptor = new RijndaelManaged ();
  cryptor.Key = key;
  cryptor.IV = iv;
  cryptor.BlockSize = 128;
  cryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

  ICryptoTransform decryptor = cryptor.CreateDecryptor (cryptor.Key, cryptor.IV);

  using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream (csEncrypted))
  {
    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream (msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
      using (StreamReader swDecrypt = new StreamReader (csDecrypt) )
      {
        csDecrypted = swDecrypt.ReadToEnd ();
      }
    }
  }
  System.Console.WriteLine ("Decrypted CS string: \"" + csDecrypted + "\"");

  using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream (phpEncrypted))
  {
    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream (msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
      using (StreamReader swDecrypt = new StreamReader (csDecrypt) )
      {
        phpDecrypted = swDecrypt.ReadToEnd ();
      }
    }
  }

  System.Console.WriteLine ("Decrypted PHP string: \"" + phpDecrypted + "\"");      
}
```

The PHP results:

> Decrypted PHP string: "This is the original String! How cool is that?"
>
> Decrypted CS string: "This is the original String! How cool is that?"

And the C# results:

> Decrypted CS string: "This is the original String! How cool is that?"
>
> CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0.
>    at Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.ThrowBadPaddingException (PaddingMode padding, Int32 length, Int32 position) [0x0005c] in > /Applications/buildAgent/work/84669f285f6a667f/mcs/class/corlib/Mono.Security.Cryptography/SymmetricTransform.cs:363

So, basically, the PHP code can successfully decrypt both base64 strings, but the C# code can only decrypt base64 strings that were created by its own decryptor.

A lot of this is code I found on the internet and modified to suit my needs.  Like I said, I'm a newbie with cryptography, but I've gotten decently far here.  I could theorize and test all day, but it's starting to eat into my schedule so I'm looking for insights from others as to why it isn't working.  Thank you!

Comment: Try ASCII.GetBytes instead of UTF8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [**PHPSecLib**](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) because the `PHP` implementation is not compatible with `C++/C#`. It has a different padding size *(not a crypto expert here but this is what I found after days of testing)*. So use the native implementations in the `phpseclib` and it will work.

Bumped into this issue a while ago myself. But with `C++` / `CryptoAPI` and `PHP`.

Comment: Oh yuck... I was trying to avoid using libraries, but I'll definitely give this a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: @TomMurray No worries! It's a good license... and there's no other choice :)

Comment: Your mention regarding padding size was actually the key to solving the issue.  After googling that for a bit, I found a comment on the [PHP Mcrypt page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) that points out padding sizes.  After setting the padding size with this: `rijndaelObject.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros`, it works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: In general, PKCS#7 padding should be greatly preferred to zero padding, because the latter is ambiguous – how do you differentiate between a message that ends with zero bytes and a message that is padded with zero bytes?

Comment: The comment from Tom Murray was extremly helpful, when we run into the same issue! Thanks tom!!